# Failed assertion '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true with StreamBuilder / ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I use a StreamBuilder to get Posts from Firebase Cloud Firestore. Then, I use a ListView to display it on the screen. But sometimes, some posts doesn't appear and I get the error message "Failed assertion: line 1695 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true".

```
 return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      ...
    ),
    body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _postsQuery,
        builder: (context, postSnapshot) {
          if (postSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return LoadingIndicator();
          }
          if (postSnapshot.hasData) {
            _postListSnapshot = postSnapshot.data.documents;

            return NotificationListener(
              onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
                if (scrollInfo.metrics.pixels == scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
                  _loadMorePosts();
                }
              return true;
            },
              child: ListView.builder(
                    reverse: false,
                    itemCount: _postListSnapshot.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                     ...
                    }

                ),
            );
          }
          else {
           ...
          }
        }
    )
);
```

this is how I get posts :

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _getPosts() {

    Stream<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot;

    querySnapshot = Firestore.instance
      .collection('posts')
      .where('userList', arrayContains: widget.user.uid)
      .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
      .snapshots();

    return querySnapshot;
 }
```

and the load more posts :

```
_loadMorePosts() {

 if (_postListSnapshot != null && _lastPostDate != null) {

  Firestore.instance
      .collection('posts')
      .where('createdAt', isLessThan: _lastPostDate)
      .limit(3)
      .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
      .getDocuments()
      .then((snapshot) {
        setState(() {
          _postListSnapshot.addAll(snapshot.documents);
        });
  });
 }

}
```

Comment: Your code looks okay but the error isn't sufficient to know what the problem is exactly, if it works sometimes and doesn't work some other time, it could possibly be from the data you are fetching. Check closely your data consistency. Maybe keywords or datatypes. Also, test every step of your code process to know exactly where the problem originates from.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit in this issue is that the snapshot is null. `postSnapshot.hasData` can still return true even if the data in it is null. A null-check on `_postListSnapshot` before passing it on to `ListView.builder()` should fix the issue.

```dart
if (postSnapshot.hasData && postSnapshot != null) {
  // Display ListView
} else {
  // Display ProgressIndicator
}
```